# checkbox hiding and showing component - react

Tags: reactjs

I am building a small feature that has a checkbox styled as slider that, when turned on and off, should display another component - `BatchWidget`. The way I have it currently set up, it works on initial page load, and then hides as intended. However, when I go to "toggle" it back on to show the component again, it does not work. Is there an easy solution to this?

```
const Slider = (props) => {
   return (
     <div className="slider-container">
       <label className="switch">
         <input type="checkbox" checked={props.checked} onClick= {props.showWidget} />
         <span className="slider round" />
       </label>
       <p className="batch-slider-title"> Batch Widget </p>
     </div>
   );
 };

 const Settings = ({showSlider}) => {
   return (
     <div className="settings">
       <i className="icon-gear" onClick={() => showSlider()} />
     </div>
   );
 }

 class WidgetContainer extends Component {

    constructor() {
      super();

    this.state = {
      checked: true,
      isSliderDisplayed: false,
    };

    this.showWidget = this.showWidget.bind(this);
    this.showSlider = this.showSlider.bind(this);
  }

   showWidget() {
     this.setState({
       checked: !this.state.checked,
     });
   }

   showSlider() {
      this.setState({
        isSliderDisplayed: !this.state.isSliderDisplayed,
   });
 }

   render() {
     const displayBatchWidget = this.state.checked ? <BatchWidget /> : null;
     const displaySlider = this.state.isSliderDisplayed ? <Slider checked={this.state.checked} showWidget={this.showWidget} /> : null;
     return (
       <div>
         <Settings showSlider={this.showSlider} />
         {displaySlider}
         {displayBatchWidget}
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to debug, it shows:

```
Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `Slider`.
```

I think it is self-explanatory.

I've changed the line with checkbox to:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={props.checked} onChange= {props.showWidget} />
```

Now, the batchWidget should hide and show on each click.

Comment: I changed it to onChange and the warning error went away, but still the same behavior

Comment: Still not getting it to work, I'll investigate further

Comment: Since there is no BatchWidget in the snippet, I're replaced it with a span. It worked, so double check your BatchWidget components.

Answer (score 0):

**Reactjs matrial ui table check box hide**

first do  
`<Table selectable={false}>
<TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>`

this method hide  table header check box
then do `<TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>`
it hide table body checkbox
**it work perfect.**

> reactjs